# Left (Outer) Joins with Linq - Contradiction with "into" in examples I found

Tags: vb.net, linq

I found this [example](http://www.ozkary.com/2011/07/linq-to-entity-inner-and-left-joins.html)

The author mentions the following line

```
join cat in en.Category on proc.catid equals cat.catid into catList
```

When I try to use the "into" keyword, the color stays black instead of turning  blue. There isn't even a suggestion with Intelisense.

And when I drag my mouse cursor over that "into", it tells me that there's a missing ")"

```
Dim result = (From foo In Entity.Foo
                  Join bar In Entity.Bar On foo.ID Equals bar.ID into foobarJoined 
                  From foobar In foobarJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  Select New With {
                      ' [...]
                      })
```

Could it be that there's a difference between Linq under C# and VB? I am using the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Dim result =   From foo In Entity.Foo
               Group Join bar In  Entity.Bar On
               foo.ID Equals bar.ID
               Into foobarJoined = Group
               Select New With {
                  ' [...]
               })
```

Query syntax in VB is a little different than C#. Check this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531303.aspx) page for more details about ***Group Join***.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this *JOIN* syntax (see below). To me, it is easier to read

```
Dim result = 
    From foo In Entity.Foo
    From bar in Entity.Bar.Where(Function(r) r.FooId = foo.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    Select New With 
        {
            ' . . . . . .
        })
```

This is equivalent of Left Join